# Java: Arrays of Objects; what is the difference between local and class-level instances?

Tags: java, arrays, object, initialization, default-value

As far as the initial/default/uninitialized value of is concerned...
...Are array objects initialized (at class and local levels)?

Read it in some SCJP notes:

> Array elements are given their default values regardless of whether
>   the array is declared as an instance or local variable.
>
> Array "objects" however will not be initialized if it is declared
>   locally.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by your question?

Comment: Please have a look at John Skeet's blog post on [how to ask the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more on what information would help us.

Comment: Edited question, see again please

Comment: @pop stack: congratulations: you found the answer to your question in the JLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class members that are reference types get an initial value of null.

Local variables that are reference types are considered unitialized and need to be assigned null or something else explicitly, else the code will not compile.

Try to test this example and see what happens:

```
class Test {
    private Object[] member;

    public void foo() {
        member.toString(); // NullPointerException
        Object[] local;
        local.toString(); // won't compile: The local variable local may not have been initialized
    }
}
```

Arrays of objects obey the same rules, since they are references themselves.

Now, that's for the array itself. When speaking about **the actual elements of the array**, they are null by default regardless of where you declare them:

```
class Test {
    private Object[] member = new Object[10];

    public void foo() {
        member[0].toString(); // NullPointerException
        Object[] local = new Object[10];
        local[0].toString(); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An uninitialized object is always `null`.

```
Object[] myArray;
//myArray == null

myArray = new Object[1];
//myArray[0] == null
```

Comment: Not really. Your first array is implicitely initialized to null if it's an instance or static variable. It's uninitialized if it's a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

An array declared as a field is initialized to null, like every non-primitive instance variable. An array declared as a local variable is uninitialized, as every other local variable.

Once initialized to a new array, both contain null for each of their elements.

Answer (score 1):

1`.In JAVA local variable have to intitialized before using it.`

```
2. String s[] = new String[2];
Here s[0] and s[1] both contains NULL value and initialize s[0] and s[1] as:
s[0] = new String();
s[1] = new String();
```